# Trying to pass an object to an external route file using Nodejs and Expess

Tags: node.js, express

I have my nodeapp and an external route file. 
I am trying to pass the object clientMap to the external router

When i try to pass using syntax from examples

```
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)(clientMap);
```

i always get the error

> node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:140 var search = 1 +
>
> req.url.indexOf('?');
>
> TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
>       at Function.handle

This is how i have it currently(just snippets cause this is a big app), which does not work

app.js

```
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var apiRoutes = require('./routes/apiRoutes');
app.use('/api', apiRoutes)(clientMap);
```

apiRoutes.js

```
module.exports = (function (clientMap) {

    var router = express.Router();
    router.use(function (req, res, next) {

    });

    router.get('/userlist', function (req, res, next) {
    });


    return router;

})();
```

I have also tried and get the same error

```
app.use('/api', apiRoutes(clientMap));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing to `apiRoutes`, not `app.use`:

```
app.use('/api', apiRoutes(clientMap));
```

You also want to be exporting a function as `apiRoutes`, not calling it as an IIFE:

```
module.exports = function (clientMap) {

    var router = express.Router();
    router.use(function (req, res, next) {

    });

    router.get('/userlist', function (req, res, next) {
    });


    return router;

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the original question. I still get the same error

Comment: I think i saw the other problem. Updated.